# Why is the following expectation inequality true?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables, why is the following inequality true:

$$|\mathbb{E}X_1 - \mathbb{E}X_2| \leq \mathbb{E}|X_1 - X_2|$$

Comment: $\int f\,d\mu \leq \int \lvert f \rvert\, d\mu$

Comment: As well as the linearity of expectation.

Comment: Actually one must use $|\int f| \leq \int |f|$, which is less trivial than just $\int f \leq \int |f|$.

Comment: @xyzzyz it follows from the same inequality by considering $-f$.

Comment: An alternative is Jensen's inequality.